# How to Prevent Terraform From Replacing ECS Service with CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

**Original**

I'm using AWS CodeDeploy to update an ECS Service. During a CodeDeploy deployment, it will change the target group from how it's configured in Terraform. This creates a problem because Terraform will then overwrite the current load balancer and cause the service to be temporarily unavailable.

How can I tell Terraform to avoid changing the target group? I've tried using a `lifecycle` block  but then Terraform fails to apply because it looks like there's no load balancer at all.

Maybe a better question would be, how can I manage Terraform updates and CodeDeploy in the same application?

Here's what the change to Terraform looks like after a CodeDeploy.

```
  - load_balancer { # forces replacement
      - container_name   = "service" -> null
      - container_port   = 3000 -> null
      - target_group_arn = "{...}service-green{...}" -> null
    }
  + load_balancer { # forces replacement
      + container_name   = "service"
      + container_port   = 3000
      + target_group_arn = "{...}service{...}"
    }
```

**Example**

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "default" {
  name                               = "service"
  cluster                            = "cluster"
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  task_definition                    = definition.default.arn
  desired_count                      = 1

  deployment_controller {
    type = var.deployment_controller_type
  }

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = aws_security_group.service[*].id
    subnets         = data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids
  }

  dynamic "load_balancer" {
    for_each = local.load_balancers.public.enabled ? [1] : []
    content {
      target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.public[load_balancer.key].arn
      container_name   = local.service_name
      container_port   = var.container_port
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      desired_count,
      task_definition
    ]
  }
}
```

Attempted solution:

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      desired_count,
      task_definition,
      load_balancer
    ]
     prevent_destroy = true
  }
```

Comment: Why woudn't be there a load balancer? CD does not changes LBs, but only TGs?

Comment: Because of the lifecycle block I'm adding is ignoring changes for `load_balancer`.

Comment: @Marcin I've added an example

Comment: Maybe the hook should be under the load_balancer block.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it (thanks to your question here, actually), by using

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "lb_https_listeners"
  ...
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [default_action[0].target_group_arn]
  }
```

But if you try and use a splat, you get

```
A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and
indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template
expressions, etc are allowed here.
```

You might be able to use a dynamic block for ignore changes? I didn't try 'cause even though I currently have a dynamic block I'm only using one for the forseeable future.